# Choosing coefficients that imply the solution of system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following system of equations:

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\beta_1a=\beta_3c\\
\beta_2c=\beta_1b\\
\beta_3b=\beta_2a
\end{cases}
\end{align}

I want to choose such $a,b,c\in\Bbb{C}$ that would imply that the only solution to these equations would be $\beta_1=\beta_2=\beta_3=0$. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move all terms to the left side of each equation and rewrite as a matrix equation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & -c \\
-b & c & 0 \\
0 & -a & b
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_1 \\
\beta_2 \\
\beta_3 
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This has a unique solution if and only if the matrix determinant is nonzero. That determinant is 
$$ 
a(c)(b) - c(-b)(-a) = 0
$$

In other words, there's no choice of $a,b,c$ for which the solution is unique.